# how to transfer fund from msg.sender(amount) to recipient address without using setting msg.value

Tags: ethereum, solidity

We can transfer funds from address(this) to recipient. But is there any way to transfer funds directly msg.sender wallet to recipient? I can not set msg.value at the time of invoking payoutBonus call. Because I can get the amount only inside payoutBonus method.

```
function payoutBonus(address recipient) public payable returns (bool) {
    // bonus = calculateBonus();
    //transfer this bonus to recipient from msg.sender;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: msg.sender.send()

Answer (score 6):

`msg.value` is a read-only property reflecting value of the incoming transaction. If you want to send an ETH amount, you can do it in one of two ways.

Notes:

- These examples work on Solidity 0.8. Some previous versions also allow the `send()` method that is now deprecated, don't require the `payable` type, and have slightly different syntax for the `call()` method.
- `bonus` is amount of wei (1 ETH is 10^18 wei)

#### The `transfer()` method

```
uint256 bonus = calculateBonus();
payable(msg.sender).transfer(bonus);
```

The `transfer()` method only allows consuming 2300 gas, which is enough for non-contract recipients. If the recipient is a contract requiring more than 2300 gas to receive the ETH (for instance it sets some local variable), the transaction reverts.

#### Low-level `call()`

```
uint256 bonus = calculateBonus();
msg.sender.call{value: bonus}("");
```

With the low-level `call()` method, you can also specify the gas limit, function to call and it's arguments. **Use this method only if you know what you're doing.**

Comment: I have seen a couple people use your low level call example, but i'm having trouble finding any sort of documentation on it, and i don't really recognize the syntax. Like what does the curly braces before the parentheses mean, and why are you passing an empty string as an argument? Are you able to point me in the direction of some documentation for this?

Comment: @LucasRahn The options (in curly braces) are briefly mentioned for example in [External Function Calls](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/control-structures.html#external-function-calls) or [Members of Addresses](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html#members-of-addresses). But I agree that the low-level call in general is currently not very well documented.